# What's the part of a lampshade that the finial screws into called?

Tags: lamp

I inherited a floor lamp without a shade.  It has a harp, but there is nothing on the top of the harp to attach the shade.  If I have my terminology correct, I'm looking for the piece that that the finial will screw into.  It's circled in this photo.  What's this called, and can I buy one with a finial so I can buy a shade for the lamp?  Or should I just buy a new harp (that presumably will come with this piece)?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just was looking for one a few weeks ago.  I saw them under a few names "harp fitter", "spider fitter", or "lamp adjuster".  I just got a new harp it was easier.

Answer (score 3):

I worked in a real lighting store for several years in my teens and early 20's. I was responsible for many purchase orders, quite a few from the likes of Angelo and Wn DeSherbenin.

That piece is crimped onto the harp. I have never seen it available separately. You simply need to replace the harp.

Answer (score -2):

I think what both of you are talking about is simply called a finial. You thread it onto the screw at the top of the harp. You don't have to buy a whole new harp. Finials are sold in the lamp department everywhere. You can choose a plain one or a decorative one to "dress up" a lampshade.

Comment: Per the question "I'm looking for the piece that that the finial will screw into"